# How to send a string and data from iOS to Php for creating a table in MySQL database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, json

I'm trying to find a way to pass a string and a json data file to an online Php file, which will create a table in a MySQL database using the string as the table name, and put the json data into the table. So far I have the following code on the iOS side:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWebAddress/uploadData.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:self.myData];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionDataTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        } else {
            self.textLabel.text=@"Data uploaded to database!";
        }
    }];
    [sessionDataTask resume];
```

On the web side, I have the following Php code:

```
<?php
$json_data=file_get_contents('php://input', true);
$post_data = json_decode($json_data);
$dbc=mysql_connect("mysql", "userName", "password");
mysql_select_db("myDatabase");
foreach($post_data as $lineData)
{$lastName=$lineData->lastName;
$firstName=$lineData->firstName;
$company=$lineData->company;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `peopleDataTable` (`lastName`, `firstName`, `company`) VALUES ('$lastName', '$firstName', '$company')");}
mysql_close($dbc);
if (is_array($post_data))
$response = array("status" => "ok", "code" => 0, "original request" => $post_data);
else
$response = array("status" => "error", "code" => -1, "original_request" => $post_data);
$processed = json_encode($response);
echo $processed;
?>
```

Could you help me to find a solution to modify this codes so that I can send a string to the Php, and use the string to specify the table name "peopleDataTable"?

Or I should completely modify the code?

Thank you very much!

Paul

Comment: You can send that string with JSON and fetch from php side. Like in your self.myData add key value pair **"tblName : name"** and in php side access it with **"$post_data->tblName"**. If you have still doubt then let me know will explain you in detail.

Comment: @EktaMakadiya Thank you for your reply. I have two detailed questions then, could you help me on them? Firstly, how can I put two arrays with different entities or dictionary types into one single Json file in iOS? Should I combine two arrays first or combine two Json files? Secondly, on the php side, how can I single out data point for each type of entity? Is it just like what you suggested "$post_data->tblname" and "$post_data->people"? So it will become " foreach($post_data->tblname as $lineData)". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the below link to pass data as parameter , else you can use AFNetwork for data transfer which has pretty easy methods.

http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/

```
-(void)requestFunction:(NSString *)main_url :(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters :(BOOL)post
{
     __block NSString *response_string;
     __block NSData *objectData;
     __block NSMutableDictionary *json;
    NSURL *baseURL=[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];

    manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];


    if (post == NO)
    {
        [manager GET:main_url parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
         {
             response_string=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             objectData = [response_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSError *jsonError;
             json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                      error:&jsonError];
               [[self delegate] apiResponse:json];
            } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
                {
                      STOP_LOAD;
                       NSLog(@"%@",error);
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Error, Please try again later"
                                                                 message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                  [alertView show];
                  }];

    }
    else
    {
        [manager POST:main_url parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
        {
            response_string=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            objectData = [response_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *jsonError;
            json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                     error:&jsonError];
           // [self requestComplete:json];
               [[self delegate] apiResponse:json];

        }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",error);
                    STOP_LOAD;
                        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Error,Please try again later"
                                                                               message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                              delegate:nil
                                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
                           [alertView show];

                  }];
    }


}
```

You can see my code , i just call this method like below,

```
-(void)Login: (NSString *) User_fb_id
{
     NSMutableDictionary *api_call_parameter=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [api_call_parameter setObject:User_fb_id forKey:@"user_fb_id"];
      [api_call_parameter setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"device_type"];
      [api_call_parameter setObject:Device_Token forKey:@"device_id"];

      [self requestFunction:LOGIN :api_call_parameter :YES];
}
```

So you can pass the data through this dictionary as parameter.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Karthik. Do you know how to send a string and a json data object together with the [NSMutableURLRequest set Value:] and [NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody:]? what should be the the right grammar?